# Ajuste da Div Pai CSS

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div id="fotos-listagem">
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/1348357833.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/1075751499.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/422227837.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/286290440.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/957801387.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="upload-multiplo" name="fotos_ingresso" id="fotos_ingresso" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

E o seguinte CSS:

```
#fotos-listagem {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    min-height: ;
}

#fotos-listagem-imagem {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left !important;
}
.corte-imagem {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

Porém, na hora de visualizar fica dessa forma: O background cinza fica embaixo, mas não acompanha o tamanho da div que está dentro. Como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque as divs internas estão flutuadas. Elementos flutuados não influem nas dimensões dos ancestrais. A solução é simples, basta colocar `overflow: hidden` em `#fotos-listagem` (um truque para quebrar contexto de floats) para que o browser passe a considerar a altura dos filhos.

```css
#fotos-listagem {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

#fotos-listagem-imagem {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left !important;
}
.corte-imagem {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="fotos-listagem">
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/1348357833.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/1075751499.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/422227837.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/286290440.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <img src="http://localhost/proyectopen/assets/uploads/interno_fotos/ingresso/957801387.jpg" class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="upload-multiplo" name="fotos_ingresso" id="fotos_ingresso" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado! :)